# How to display User name as a page title

Tags: seo, liferay, velocity, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

from last few days i am trying to do some modification in SEO level, as i am working on a social portal. when i goes thru any users profile. the page title comes on window tab is

> "Profile|XYZ.com"

If i went thru a user

> "TestUser"'s

profile,it must show

> "TestUser|XYZ.com"

Currently its shwoing

> profile|XYZ.com.

i am bit new in velocity as i think it coming from portal_normal.vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think currently it is showing as

$the_title - $company_name

if you want to show user's name, you can try following in portal_normal.vm

$$user_name | $company_name

Comment: You are late but thanks :P
as we know groups are site in LR6.1 and above, so $site_name works fine for me in portal_normal.vm file :)